# Report only refused to connect to <URL> because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive

Tags: angular, content-security-policy

I've been having problems with an Angular app, as soon as i go to one of the modules, i get this type of errors, which prevents the app to work normally

First, it says that refused to load a script
[image]

Then refused to connect to that URL
[image]
I'd like to know what are we missing, or if is this a configuration we need to setup

Answer (score 1):

Your site has a Content Security Policy set in report-only mode. This means that even though you see the errors, the content is not actually being blocked. If something isn't working, it is likely due to something else. You should still fix the CSP errors to be able to enforce your policy.

The simplest modification needed to remove these errors is to add bam.nr-data.net to your default-src directive. If you implement script-src (or script-src-elem) and connect-src you should add it to those as well.